# Match people based on specific elements in a nested array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a MongoDB collection like this:

```
_id: ObjectId("5cb089e459552d8b8cc6a9e4")
username: "admin"
password: "12345"
gender: "male"
interestedIn: "female"
movie: Array
  0: Object
    id: "Avatar"
    title: "Avatar"
    poster: "~"
  1: Object
    id: "Titanic"
    title: "Titanic"
    poster: "~"
```

I have two other persons (females) like this where one has "Avatar" and the other one "Titanic" in their movie interest. 
Now I want to match people based on the gender they're interested in and when they share the same movie interest. The function I tried for this is as follow:

```
function matches(req, res) {
    db.collection('user').find({ 'username': req.session.user.username })
      .toArray(function(err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('An error has occurred', err);
        } else {
            let interest = data[0].interestedIn;
            let movies = data[0].movie;

            db.collection('user').find({
                gender: interest,
                movie: { $elemMatch: { id: 'Avatar' }}
            }).toArray(function(err, data) {
                res.render('matches.pug', {
                    data,
                    user: req.session.user,
                    interest,
                    movies
                });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

When I run this code, I only get back the one girl who also has "Avatar" as her movie interest since I wrote `id: 'Avatar'` on the `$elemMatch`. However, I want to be able to return **all** persons who share the same movie interest. Is there a way I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly your question, you can use $in to get all documents that match at least one of the values, here's an example:

```
      db.collection('user').find({
        gender: interest,
        movie: { $in: movies}
    })
```

[Fiddle](https://play.db-ai.co/m/XNLFaKBXLQABKmRM/edit?key=bJN6Yhu2KF8)

Answer (score 0):

The "$in" operator should solve your problem.
You could use something like:

```
db.collection('user').find({
    gender: interest,
    movie: { $in: movies}
})
```

Another tip, you can match multiple elements from the array. $in would return you the record if at least one match is found in "movie" from the "movies" array which you are passing.

If you want to get the document only when all the movies in the "movies" array are present in "movie", use "$all".

[Ref: MongoDB Documentation][1]: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/